# Why is this div element encapsulated by the previous div element?

Tags: html, css, css-position

In this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/whp88tfo/2/) that I was playing around with, I made a `div#footer` that started to behave weirdly.

For now, its CSS is set to:

```
div#footer {
    width: calc(100% + 100px);
    margin-left: -50px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

It's positioned staticly and supposed to sit below the other `<div>`s, which are the `div#header` and `div#body`. But for some reason, it seems as though it *takes up* the `div#body` as well. See this image, for example:

[image: screenshot]

Notice how the `box-shadow` effect is applying to the entire `div#body` element. The bottom two centered lines should be all of the `div#footer`.

`div#body` is also set to `position:static` (default). I didn't add any specific styles to it (but I did to some of its children elements).

I don't know what's going on -- this has never happened to me before. The full code is on the JSfiddle, but it's too much for me to post here. Any ideas on what is happening and solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `div#body` element is collapsing upon itself.

When elements are absolutely positioned **or** floated (as in your case), they are removed from the normal flow of the document. Here is relevant documentation confirming this:

> [**9 Visual formatting model - 9.5 Floats**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats)
>
> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not exist. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box of the float.

In your case, all the direct children elements of the `div#body` element are floated. Due to this, the `div#body` element essentially collapses upon it self since it doesn't have any dimensions.

You need to apply [a clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix) to the `div#body` element, for instance:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6x3rfdg2/)

```
#body {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

or:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/058pwwc1/)

```
#body:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also add `clear: both` to the `#footer` element:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pkqqb25t/)

```
#footer {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I've heard of this, but I didn't know what it meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're missing a [**clearfix**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/211383/3597276) solution for the `div#body` element, as it has children that are floated. Try this:

```
div#body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/whp88tfo/3/) (with borders added for illustration)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!